# How to find/replace specific object in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have simple image upload via `action` and `mutation`. The main thing is that I firstly want to store preloader and then, when the image is uploaded to the server show the image and remove preloader.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        images: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        addImage(state, image) {
            state.images.push(image);
        }
    },
    actions: {
        saveImage({commit}, image) {
            commit('addImage', {url: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=loading...'});

            let form_data = new FormData();

            form_data.append('file', image);

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url  : '/api/v1/products/files/save',
                    data : form_data,
                    type : 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: response => {
                        // commit('addImage', response.file);

                        // here I somehow need to replace/readd the response.file

                        resolve(response.file)
                    }
                }).fail(() => reject())
            })
        }
    },
    strict: debug
})
```

I basically could use `array.find` method to look for `url:http://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=loading...` remove it and then add new one  but not sure if it's is the right method...

Answer (score 0):

You give vuex action too much to do. Let it do one single task - upload the file. The placeholder/preloader should be handled by the component even without a vuex state. All the component needs to know is whether the image is uploading or not in order to show the loading indicator. Since your action returns a Promise your component will know when it's ready.

Comment: The preloader is show for each image. For example if i select 10 images at first I will show 10 preloaders ad each time the image is uploaded i need to replace the preloader with real image.